# QScopedPointer кастомный deleter

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Ничего не понимаю, каким образом мне передать в конструктор `QScopedPointer` функцию `deleter`'a, как я это делал в `std::unique_ptr`?

> error: C2440: : невозможно преобразовать
>   "initializer list" в "VlcInstancePtr"

```
struct VlcDeleter
{
    static inline void InstanceCleanup(libvlc_instance_t *&pointer)
    {
        libvlc_release(pointer);
        pointer = nullptr;
    }

    static inline void MediaPlayerCleanup(libvlc_media_player_t *&pointer)
    {
        libvlc_media_player_release(pointer);
        pointer = nullptr;
    }

    static inline void MediaCleanup(libvlc_media_t *&pointer)
    {
        libvlc_media_release(pointer);
        pointer = nullptr;
    }
};

typedef QScopedPointer<libvlc_instance_t, void(*)(libvlc_instance_t*)> VlcInstancePtr;
typedef QScopedPointer<libvlc_media_player_t, void(*)(libvlc_media_player_t*)> VlcMediaPlayerPtr;
typedef QScopedPointer<libvlc_media_t, void(*)(libvlc_media_t*)> VlcMediaPtr;
```

При таком раскладе, не могу инициализировать `QScopedPointer` таким образом:

```
vlcInstance_ = VlcInstancePtr(libvlc_new(0, 0), &VlcInstanceDeleter::cleanup);
vlcMediaPlayer_ = VlcMediaPlayerPtr(libvlc_media_player_new(vlcInstance_.data()), &VlcMediaPlayerDeleter::cleanup);
QString path = QString("path/to/");
vlcMedia_ = VlcMediaPtr(libvlc_media_new_path(vlcInstance_.data(), path.toUtf8().data()), &VlcMediaDeleter::cleanup);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QScopedPointer не умеет принимать deleter в качестве аргумента конструктора. Делетер передается в качестве 2-го параметра шаблона и не может быть переопределен в run-time. Сделайте так:

```
struct VlcDeleter
{
    static void cleanup(libvlc_instance_t *&pointer)
    {
        libvlc_release(pointer);
        pointer = nullptr;
    }
    static void cleanup(libvlc_media_player_t *&pointer)
    {
        libvlc_media_player_release(pointer);
        pointer = nullptr;
    }
    static void cleanup(libvlc_media_t *&pointer)
    {
        /libvlc_media_release(pointer);
        pointer = nullptr;
    }
};


typedef QScopedPointer<libvlc_instance_t    , VlcDeleter> VlcInstancePtr;
typedef QScopedPointer<libvlc_media_player_t, VlcDeleter> VlcMediaPlayerPtr;
typedef QScopedPointer<libvlc_media_t       , VlcDeleter> VlcMediaPtr;
```

Инициализация переменной:

```
VlcInstancePtr vlcInstance_( libvlc_new(0, 0) );
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы еще подсказать как мне его теперь инициализировать в конструкторе? Он думает что я пытаюсь его копировать.